# A question regarding momentum of inertia of L-shaped bar

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia

I have trouble deriving moment of inertia $\Theta_A$ of the bar rotating around the point A shown in the image.

The answer of the problem says:
$\Theta_A=\frac{m}{3}\frac{a^2}{3}+\left[\frac{(2a)^2}{12}+(a^2+a^2)\frac{2m}{3}\right]$.

I understand the first part of RHS of the equation which is the moment of inertia of the shorter member. However, I have trouble deriving the second part which is the moment of inertia of the longer member.

Can someone give me a detailed procedure of the derivation?
[image]

Ref:Dietmar Gross et al, Dynamics-Formulas and Problems, Springer

Comment: Your formulas look wrong, for example you have $a^2+a^2$.

Comment: Well, the formula is exactly the same with what is shown in the model answer. Maybe, errata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first term inside the bracket is missing a factor of mass.

To derive the moment of inertia of the rod of length $2a$, the parallel axes theorem can be applied.

If $I$ is the moment of inertia about the axis through the hinge (which lies outside the rod), and $I_{c}$ is the moment of inertia about the axis through the centre of mass of the rod, with $d$ being the perpendicular distance between the axes, the theorem states that

$I=I_{c}+Md^{2}$

Using the well known result for the moment of inertia of a rod

$I_{c} = \frac{2m (2a)^2}{3 * 12} = \frac{2ma^2}{9}$

And,

$Md^2 = \frac{2m}{3} * (a^2 + a^2) = \frac{4ma^2}{3} $

Observe here that the distance between the CM axis and the hinge axis is $d = \sqrt{2a^2}$ by Pythagoras' theorem.

Now we get

$ I = \frac{2ma^2}{9} + \frac{4ma^2}{3} = \frac{14ma^2}{9}$

This is the moment of inertia of the longer rod. The given answer appears to be incorrect.

Comment: I appreciate your explaination. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let x be the distance measured along the "a" side and let y be the distance (from the bend) measured along the 2a side.  Let $\rho$ represent the mass per unit length along the rod ($\rho=m/3a$).  Then the moment of inertia about the hinge is $$I=\int_0^a{\rho x^2dx}+\int_0^{2a}{\rho (a^2 + y^2)dy}=\rho(\frac{a^3}{3}+2a^3+\frac{8a^3}{3})$$$$=5\rho a^3=5m\frac{a^2}{3}$$The portion of this result for the longer rod is consistent with what @FundamentalTheorem obtained.

Comment: I appreciate your explaination. Thank you!